# 'FormWindowState' Does Not Exist In the Current Context

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012, expression-blend

I am working with **WPF through blend and Visual Studio 2012**. Every time I try to use certain code I keep getting errors like this. For the life of me I can't figure it out. Any help is appreciated, and any explanations would be great.

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Edit: To see the image more clear, right click it and choose "Open in new tab" if available.

Thanks, I updated my code. Now It's giving me a new error.

Screenshot:
[image]

**Error: Error 1   'Titan.MainWindow.WindowMaximizeButton' is a 'field' but is used like a 'method'    C:\Users\Jake\Documents\Expression\Blend 4\Projects\Titan\Titan\MainWindow.xaml 202 91  Titan**

## XAML Code:

```
        <Button x:Name="WindowMaximizeButton" Content="Button" Width="14.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource WindowMaximizeButton}" Click="WindowMaximizeButton" Margin="0,0,48.998,0">

<Window
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:Microsoft_Windows_Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero"
    x:Class="Titan.MainWindow"
    x:Name="Titan"
    Title="Titan"
    Width="880" Height="474" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Maximized" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Background="#FF0F0F0F">

    <Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="ButtonFocusVisual">
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBackground" EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
            <GradientStop Color="#F3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#EBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#DDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#CDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
        <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonNormalBorder" Color="#FF707070"/>
        <Style x:Key="WindowExitButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOver">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Maroon"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="20" Margin="-14,0,-3,0" Width="Auto">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="Black">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF210000" Offset="0.978"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4D0000"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Image x:Name="image" Source="appbar.close.png" Margin="-5,-3.5,-4.5,-3.5"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WindowMaximizeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOver">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Maroon"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="20" Margin="-14,0,-3,0" Width="Auto">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="Black">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF210000" Offset="0.978"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4D0000"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Image x:Name="image" Source="appbar.tablet.windows.png" Margin="-5,-3.5,-4.5,-3.5"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        <Style x:Key="WindowMinimizeButton" TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource ButtonFocusVisual}"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBackground}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource ButtonNormalBorder}"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
            <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Button}">
                        <ControlTemplate.Resources>
                            <Storyboard x:Key="MouseOver">
                                <ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(GradientBrush.GradientStops)[1].(GradientStop.Color)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                    <EasingColorKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.2" Value="Maroon"/>
                                </ColorAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            </Storyboard>
                        </ControlTemplate.Resources>
                        <Grid x:Name="grid" Height="20" Margin="-14,0,-3,0" Width="Auto">
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" Stroke="Black">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF210000" Offset="0.978"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="#FF4D0000"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <Image x:Name="image" Source="appbar.window.minimize.png" Margin="-5,-3.5,-4.5,-3.5" Opacity="0.995"/>
                        </Grid>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Trigger.ExitActions>
                                    <RemoveStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard"/>
                                </Trigger.ExitActions>
                                <Trigger.EnterActions>
                                    <BeginStoryboard x:Name="MouseOver_BeginStoryboard" Storyboard="{StaticResource MouseOver}"/>
                                </Trigger.EnterActions>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="ToggleButton.IsChecked" Value="true"/>
                            <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="#ADADAD"/>
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Window.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Mouse.MouseEnter" SourceName="WindowExitButton"/>
    </Window.Triggers>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
        <Rectangle Height="84" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect BlurRadius="25" Opacity="0.495"/>
            </Rectangle.Effect>
            <Rectangle.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="1"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FF101010"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Rectangle.Fill>
        </Rectangle>
        <Menu Height="35" VerticalAlignment="Top" Background="{x:Null}" Margin="0,49,0,0"/>
        <Button x:Name="WindowExitButton" Content="Button" Width="31" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource WindowExitButton}" Click="WindowExitButton_Click" Margin="0,0,2,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="WindowMaximizeButton" Content="Button" Width="14.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource WindowMaximizeButton}" Click="WindowExitButton_Click" Margin="0,0,48.998,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
        <Button x:Name="WindowMinimizeButton" Content="Button" Width="14.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource WindowMinimizeButton}" Click="WindowExitButton_Click" Margin="0,0,79.332,0">
            <Button.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFF3F3F3" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFEBEBEB" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFDDDDDD" Offset="0.5"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="#FFCDCDCD" Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Button.Background>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: It is a Winforms Class. Use WPF  WindowState.Normal. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.windowstate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: Please copy the code and the error message instead of posting unreadable screenshots

Comment: @RufusL open the image in a new tab for full resolution

Comment: From the error description, you are likely calling: `Titan.MainWindow.WindowMaximizeButton()` (using parenthesis, like a method) instead of: `Titan.MainWindow.WindowMaximizeButton`. If you double-click on the error, it should take you to the offending line of code...the line of code is not in your screenshot.

Comment: @RufusL Sorry, updated.

Comment: `Click` probably needs to point to a method, not a property (or object)

Comment: The error is in your MainWindow.xaml file.

Comment: For new errors, please ask a new question. Do not edit your question.

Comment: @Sayka im still getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is WPF. Not windows forms. So use like

```
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

FormWindowState is an enumerator for Windows Forms Applications

You might be migrating from Windows Forms development to WPF, thats why you're confused

**The next error is in this line**

```
<Button x:Name="WindowMaximizeButton" Content="Button" Width="14.333" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Style="{DynamicResource WindowMaximizeButton}" Click="WindowMaximizeButton" Margin="0,0,48.998,0">
```

at here

```
 Click="WindowMaximizeButton"
```

Here you have to assign a method name inside from the class that will be triggered when you click the button.

But you have given the name of the button itself

You need to set it like

```
Click="WindowMaximizeButton_Click"
```