# vb.net Imports needed for WPF Window class?

Tags: wpf, vb.net, extension-methods, class-library

I have a class library with extension methods and I'm trying to write an extension method that works with a Window class, from a WPF app.

When I try writing the extension to accept a parameter of type Window, I get an error that this type can't be found;

I can't seem to find an assembly to import that will resolve this error, so I thought I'd post it here to see if I'm doing something wrong.

As an example, here's a simple extension I'd like to be able to use:

```
    <Extension>
    Public Sub helloworld(window As System.Windows.Window) 'Error- type system.windows.window is not defined

        ...

    End Sub
```

But I'm getting the error that the type system.windows.window is not defined.

I've even tried adding a reference to this class library to the System.Windows assembly, and adding an imports at the top of the screen, but it doesn't help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['FormWindowState' Does Not Exist In the Current Context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29133586/formwindowstate-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: I'm not sure how it would be; This isn't an issue of using 'me' vs 'this', and the issue here isn't that the code around formwindow state didn't work, the question here is how to pass the object of a WPF window as a parameter to a function or sub, specifically what data type to use. This question/issue has nothing to do with Formwindowstate, that was just an example from code. The error I'm getting is underlined under the section 'System.Windows.Window', not the code beneath it.

Comment: Since at least VS 2017 (possibly earlier), VS has a contextual fix to add the missing reference.  It's one of the options that shows up if you hover over the red squigglies.

Comment: @Craig The only contextual fixes I was getting were to generate a new class for it, or to simplify the name to System.Windows. I've seen it fix a lot of other reference issues, but for some reason it wouldn't load it on this one. I'm on VS 2017 community

Comment: OK, that surprises me.  Good to know.  It's possible that it's community edition related, but I doubt it.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up taking a look at the references used on a normal WPF app project, and realized that there's a reference to PresentationFramework.... which is verbiage similar to...Windows Presentation Framework (WPF) ;)

I added this reference to my class library, and suddenly everything just worked.